# `3 > 2 == True` returns False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I tried an expression on my notebook cell

```
3 > 2 == True
```

and the output is **`False`** ?

Comment: This equates to `3>2 and 2 == True`, and 2 doesn't equal true

Comment: Thanks @Sayse.. This looked a little strange to me as other languages don't do this. I decided to share it https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.228193179.781505215.1707173483-133594398.1659695540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **chained comparison**.

From the docs: [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

*Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).*

So the equation becomes:

```
3 > 2  and 2 == True
True and False
False
```